# Set margins and properties of word document while export HTML Table in c#

Tags: html, ms-word, format, export, margin

I'm a french student in internship and I've to do a word export from a HTML table.

I got my `Table tableContent = new Table()` and i'm using this method for my export :

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Write(@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0           Transitional//EN"">");
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=DataTable.doc");
Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
String style = "<style>body {margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; font-size:11px;}</style>";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
tableContent.RenderControl(hw);
Response.Charset = "ISO-8859-1";
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
Response.HeaderEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
Response.Write(style);
Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

But when I read my wordfile (.doc), the selected view is "Web" in word, and when I select `"Page"` view, my table is not centered cause of a huge left-margin.

I want to know if I can set my word document to A4 format and set margins to center my table.

Answer (score -1):

it's for set margins of tabel to center

```
*
    {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;

        }
        #all
            {

                width:100%;
                margin:0px;

                }
```